# Problems with elements injected into HTML from user travel

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

when I set the `ContentDefinitionReferenceId = "api.signuporsignin"`
the login screen is shown with the elements `sing up now`
and `forgot password`
but among the html elements there is no select with the document type list that I have added. [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPAGX.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPevd.png)

Now when I change the `ContentDefinitionReferenceId = "api.selfasserted"` now if the list of document types is shown but there is no sign in button, sing Up now, forget the password.[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frou4.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPxya.png)

Answer (score 0):

When using combined sign in and sign up, you cannot add more fields to the sign in page. The observation that it breaks the formatting is expected when attempting to do so.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile#output-claims-sign-up-or-sign-in-page

When using selfAsserted, you can add more fields.
If you need more fields, this will be the only option. You will lose the sign up and forgot password links, you’ll have to add your own links if needed which go via your app to a separate B2C policy.